# Programmatically fire push notification from Azure web service?

Tags: android, sql, azure

I'm using Azure for an Android mobile app backend. I have my app service, a server and DB, as well as a notification nub. I've already got the notifications firing to the device properly when press "Test Send" in the Azure dashboard, but I'm trying to listen to the database and whenever a new entry appears in a particular table I want the user to recieve a notification with that information.

I can't seem to find any commonplace way to do this directly in the Azure dashboard offered by any service.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything you can "auto hook up" to be notified of a database table change in Azure App Service. You'll have to code up a process in your application to periodically check for new entries in your database and then fire off the notifications. To do this you can either use a Continuously Running Web Job, an Azure Function, or even an Azure Logic App connected to  your database and Notification Hubs.